# Telerik PageViewPage on PageRemoved for winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, events, telerik

I am currently facing a problem which i cannot find a solution to. 
I´m using Telerik RadPageView to manage different views. When i close a page (PageViewPage) i wish to execute some code regrading the view inserted into the page. I have tried to use the `FormClosed()` event on the view, but it is not fired.

Then i decided to try using the PageView event (`PageRemoved()`) for closing a page, but i cannot find the View object i need to access using the `sender`.
So now i´m praying someone out there can help my out of my misery ;)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FormClosed` event is only fired if you close your whole form, not only a `RadPageViewPage`. I guess you're on the right way with `PageRemoved` event. In this event, your `sender` object is your `RadPageView`. To get the current page which was removed, use the `RadPageViewEventArgs` from your event.

```
private void radPageView1_PageRemoved(object sender, RadPageViewEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Page.Text);
}
```

To get your `sender` as a `RadPageView`, have a look at this.

```
RadPageView view = (RadPageView)sender;
```

or

```
RadPageView view = sender as RadPageView;
```